# Is there any good reason for the python range function not to accept sequence arguments?

Tags: python, loops, numpy, design-patterns

As the title says, I'm wondering why the `range` builtin in its one argument form doesn't accept a sequence as its argument. I can only see positives, so I was wondering whether I am missing something obvious.

- Considering how often I and I'm sure many others have typed `range(somelist)` when they meant `range(len(somelist))` the meaning should be obvious
- I fail to see any other ways it could be interpreted in
- It would remove redundancy and one level of parenthesis nesting and save typing and line width in a location where linebreaks are especially harmful to readability
- I couldn't see it breaking any code

So my question is (please refrain from merely venting opinions)

- Are there any good (objective, Python [Zen](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) is acceptable) arguments against which I may have missed?
- Is there perhaps already a convenience function for `range(len(x))`?

Optionally (if somebody happens to know)

- Was this ever considered by the Python developers? What if any is the BDFL's position?
- Why is there no `arange_like` or `indices_like` in numpy? (Or is there?)

**Edit: I had hoped this wouldn't be necessary, but was obviously wrong. So please let me clarify: This is not at all a question about whether `range` is good or evil. Let's just for the sake of argument accept that it is part of the language and take things from there.**

Comment: providing an iterable along might not make sense... range('aseqaf') for instance

Comment: *Is there perhaps already a convenience function for range(len(x))?* Yes: `for ell in x: do something` or `[ele for ele in x]`. Python has this well handled...

Comment: @NaN The OP doesn't want `range` to split the iterable apart; he wants an implicit call to `len`, and `range(len('aseqaf'))` makes just as much sense as anything else.

Comment: In some languages like `c` stepping an index is the primary looping tool. `python` encourages iterating directly on the list. `range` is a means generating that `c` style indexing. `range` also takes `start` and `step` parameters that can't be inferred from `len()`.

Comment: @hpaulj Let me put it like that would you support deprecating `range`? Thought so,, because it has its uses. I for example am no fan of seven argument zip calls perhaps nested in an enumerate to round things off. Or differently clipping the arguments to zip to achieve given offsets; quite error prone and not very readable. But that wasn't the question, anyway. Wow, 3 close votes already; that didn't take long.

Comment: @PaulPanzer You could have shown an example where `range(len(seq))` is actually useful (currently it's easy to misinterpret the question as opinion-based or too broad). I did not vote to close because I sometimes feel the same way about `range(len(seq))` but in most cases making it easier to use `range(len(seq))` would lead to worse python code - or as it's often reffered to "_less pythonic code_" ([Transforming Code into Beautiful, Idiomatic Python](https://gist.github.com/JeffPaine/6213790) and links therein).

Comment: @MSeifert As I said I was hoping to avoid this whole pro or against `range` thing. A smidge naive perhaps. Maybe I should have said "I know we all hate `range` but since it's here to stay and we  are all lumbered with it wouldn't it ..." etc.

Comment: In a sense `range` has already been demoted.  In Py3 it no longer produces a list.  It is an object with `start`, `step`, `stop` attributes (same ones that a `slice` object has).  It's not even an iterator, though it does have a `__iter__` method.

Comment: Is that really a demotion? You know this stuff better than I but isn't it more of a general design trend? You wouldn't say the good ol' `dict` has been demoted because `.keys` and friends do no longer return lists would you?

Comment: @chepner ... that was my point, what do you do with an iterable, do you automatically get its length, or use it as provided.. I think it works fine as designed

Answer (score 5):

Because you can iterate over a sequence without `range`:

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
for item in a:
    print(item)
1
2
3
4
```

If you need the index as well use `enumerate`:

```
for idx, item in enumerate(a):
    print(idx, item)

0 1
1 2
2 3
3 4
```

and if you want to combine two or more sequences use `zip` or `itertools.zip_longest`:

```
for item1, item2 in zip(a, a[::-1]):
    print(item1, item2)

1 4
2 3
3 2
4 1
```

So there is actually (almost) never a reason to do `range(len(a))` so why should would it be useful to add a shortcut for that?

According to the Python Zen:

> Beautiful is better than ugly.
>
> Explicit is better than implicit.

Comment: + for `enumerate`.  That's the standard construct if you need indices that match an iterable. `numpy` has `ndenumerate`.

Comment: yes, for numpy there's a bunch of array-iterators as well: `nditer`, `ndindex` and `flatiter` (and of course the already mentioned `ndenumerate`). :)

Comment: I'd really like to avoid this do we need range(len(x)) chestnut, There are more than enough uses, really. >Beautiful is better than ugly.< Well, `range(a)` is more beautiful than `range(len(a))` >Explicit is better than implicit< I think in practice things that are unambigous and convenient (like `np.ones(scalar)`) trump that rule

Comment: @PaulPanzer "I'd really like to avoid this do we need range(len(x)) chestnut, There are more than enough uses, really." - In Python the iterator protocol applies to sequences, iterators and generators so `range(len(x))` is only possible in some cases (when it's a sequence) and in NumPy you seldom use `range` or `arange` because broadcasting makes that unneccessary. Except in some cases when one uses broadcasting to do really heavy stuff. So yes, there are use-cases but (according to the zen): "Special cases aren't special enough to break the rules."

Comment: Also possible in numpy: There is always `np.mgrid` and `np.ogrid`. They are (a bit) annoying to use to create an index-array: `np.mgrid[tuple(map(slice, arr.shape))]` because you can't unpack values in `[]` - but they do work :)

Comment: But these seem to me to be arguments against `range` itself, not against its acccepting sequence arguments. Obviously I don't have any statistics but my gut feeling is that `range(len())` should be a considerable fraction of all `range` calls so it's really not so much of a special case. Plus it doesn't break anything.

Comment: Could you elaborate your last comment? I think `range` is perfectly acceptable, for example when you have to do something a pre-defined number of times.

Comment: I was arguing against your "special cases aren't special enough". To me your argument seems to be that `range` is rare therefore everything connected to `range` is a special case. Whereas I would say it is the relative frequency that makes the special case. In absolute terms `range(len())` may be rare but perhaps not as a fraction of all `range` calls.

Answer (score 3):

> - Considering how often I and I'm sure many others have typed range(somelist) when they meant range(len(somelist)) the meaning should be obvious

Actually that only happens "often" for new Python users. But sooner or later (and sooner better than later) you should have learn to NOT do that. Using index to loop is vulnerable to off-by-one error. The proper and pythonic way is `for item in somelist`, as demonstrated in @MSeifert 's answer.

> - It would remove redundancy and one level of parenthesis nesting and save typing and line width in a location where linebreaks are especially harmful to readability

Personally I don't think this is a strong argument. In traditional C/C++ notation, we do `for(int i=0; i<strlen(aString); i++) {...}` all the time. That is one level of parenthesis nesting and people are fine with that. So Python's `len(somelist)` is equally normal. I think the point is, semantically, `range(length)` requires an integer N as input to clearly express that "I want an N-round iteration". Given this design contract, calling range(...) with anything other than an integer is most likely a bug. Consequently, silently casting the input into an integer would make this bug more difficult to be noticed in early stage. (PS: I got bitten by similar casting in other language, but that is off topic.)

> - I couldn't see it breaking any code
> - I fail to see any other ways it could be interpreted in

Since the standard range(...) is already designed to not accept a list, so yes, you can always override it to add the range(somelist) behavior without breaking existing code. It is your choice.

> So my question is (please refrain from merely venting opinions)
>
> - Are there any good (objective, Python Zen is acceptable) arguments against which I may have missed?

As a side note, do you know that `range(...)` also accepts multiple input parameters? `range(stop)`, `range(start, stop)`, `range(start, stop, step)`. I don't like the perspective that `range(1, 10, 2)` and `range([1, 10, 2])` would both be valid yet mean different things.

> - Is there perhaps already a convenience function for range(len(x))?

Probably not. But then again, you shouldn't need this too often. I found myself only do `range(len(somelist))` when I'm writing some "academic codes" on algorithm excercises.

Comment: I think you nailed it with "Given this design contract, calling range(...) with anything other than an integer is most likely a bug. "

Comment: "calling range(...) with anything other than an integer is most likely a bug." What's that? Mr Proper and Pythonic flirting with rigorous type checking? You want to be careful there, it's the thin end of the wedge. "is already designed to not accept a list" I can almost see GvR and his henchmen carefully tweaking the code, so it will never accept a list. "do you know that range(...) also accepts multiple input parameters?" Well, yes, hence "in its one argument form". "range([1, 10, 2])" and how frequent would that happen, d'you think?

Comment: Well if you ask me (and I'm not GvR or his henchmen, BTW), it is not about rigorous type checking. It is all about semantic. What if `range(...)` was NEVER about looping through a list? In its current form, it is not relative to list at all. So `range(integer)` is clear to me, but `range(somelist)` would need an implicit casting to translate the `somelist` into its length. This translation is semantic sugar at best, error-prone at worst. But then again, I did mention that you can do whatever you want, in your own code. You can even publish your super_cool_range package on PyPI, to fix this. :)

Comment: I hate to quibble but it does not require a cast implicit or other. Just an extension of the function interface. Nothing to be afraid of, many constructors and factories in python dynamically dispatch, arguably `range` already does what with completely changing its first argument's semantics depending on the call signature. Oh, and there is nothing wrong with syntactic sugar, it's a welcome weapon in the neverending fight with complexity. I'd say that in 90% of its use your prized iterator protocol is just syntactic sugar for the good ol' for loop complete with counter.

Answer (score 1):

It's trivial to define a function that takes that list input:

```
def lrange(alist):
    return range(len(alist))
```

If a utility function like this makes your code clear, use it.  The time cost is negligible.

`numpy` even more than core Python has lots little functions that just refine the inputs to suit the habits of one or more groups of users.